# Python program stops right away

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard

So I tried to record they keystrokes of my keyboard, when I use the python IDLE and write it in there, it works, but when i run it in the terminal with python3.8.1 it ends right away. That's the code:

```
import keyboard

def on_key(key):
    print(key)

keyboard.on_press(on_key, suppress=False)
```

Comment: Do you get any message at all?

Comment: Nope. I just tried my other programs aswell and they don't work either anymore. I will reinstall python, I hope that'll fix it.

Comment: @seven_seas Hi, reinstalling python DID solve my problem! I didn't really do anything, but it works now so thats good enough for me lol.

Comment: Programming is weird sometimes :D Happy it worked out :)